# Parameters showing as undefined - Exported function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, http, export

My exported functions parameter values are returning as undefined, my other functions work in the same fashion though. I hope you can help!

By the way - im aware that not all parameters are included but it doesnt work up until this point yet!

My function that doesnt work  in my postRequests.js file:

```
exports.getRefundCalculationApiCall = function (itemId, ngrokUrl, domain, orderId) {
    console.log('ngrokurl 2' + ngrokUrl)
    console.log('domain2' + domain)
    console.log('orderId2' + orderId)
    console.log('itemId2' + itemId)
    httpRequest.post(
        `${ngrokUrl}/${domain}/${orderId}`,
        {
            json:
                {
                    "line_items": [
                        {
                            "line_item_id": itemId, "quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
        },
        function (error, resp, body) {
            if (!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
                console.log('refund line items transactions information' + JSON.stringify(body.refund.transactions[0]));
                console.log('refund line items +++ information THIS IS THE ONE' + JSON.stringify(body.refund.refund_line_items[0]));
                refundAmount1 = JSON.stringify(body.refund.refund_line_items[0].price);
                order_id1 = body.refund.transactions[0].order_id;

                amount1 = body.refund.refund_line_items[0].amount;
                // constructing message to front-end with the refund expense.
                response = `Your refund amount would be ${refundAmount1}, for the item: ${itemName1}. Do you accept this and wish to initiate the returns process?`
                console.log('RESPONSE from getrefundCalc - work to FE?' + response)


                data = [details.chatuser, response]
                io.of('/main').to(socket.id).emit('response', data);

            }
            else {
                console.log('error' + error)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

here is me trying to call it in my index.js file:

```
console.log('ngrokurl' + ngrokUrl)
console.log('domain' + domain)
console.log('orderId' + orderId)
console.log('itemId' + itemId)
shopifyApiRequest.getRefundCalculationApiCall((itemId, ngrokUrl, domain, orderId));
```

my error:

```
ngrokurl 2undefined
domain2undefined
orderId2undefined
itemId2594597937215
errorError: Invalid URI "undefined/undefined/undefined"
```

I'm expecting a standard response. is there anything obvious im missing?

Comment: Are you sure the values are not undefined before being passed to the function? what is printed in the console.log before the function call?

Comment: You have unnecessary parentheses: `getRefundCalculationApiCall((itemId, ngrokUrl, domain, orderId));`. Should only have one set of parentheses.

Comment: `shopifyApiRequest.getRefundCalculationApiCall((itemId, ngrokUrl, domain, orderId));` === `shopifyApiRequest.getRefundCalculationApiCall(orderId);`

Comment: They aren't undefined consoling in my index file they console fine

Comment: @Adam What do you mean only one set?

Comment: Oh i've just seen yes there are two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.js file, you're calling the `getRefundCalculationApiCall` method with two sets of parentheses around the arguments:

```
shopifyApiRequest.getRefundCalculationApiCall((itemId, ngrokUrl, domain, orderId));
```

This should be written with only one set of parentheses around the arguments:

```
shopifyApiRequest.getRefundCalculationApiCall(itemId, ngrokUrl, domain, orderId);
```

The extra set of parentheses are grouping all four arguments into one and then passing that as the `itemId` argument. You end up printing the `orderId` value in the `console.log('itemId2' + itemId)` statement. The other three arguments are ignored and therefore undefined. Here's a simple example:

```js
function test(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
  console.log('arg1: ' + arg1);
  console.log('arg2: ' + arg2);
  console.log('arg3: ' + arg3);
  console.log('arg4: ' + arg4);
}

console.log('Individual arguments:\n');
test('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

console.log('Grouped arguments:\n');
test(('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'));
```

Comment: Awesome response, thanks for going into details, now I know why the error occurs and not just that it is an error.